# How to recreate an alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to build an `alert dialog` that pops on the screen if the current `user` has no location details.

Also I would to like to check  if the user has filled both `EditTexts` and if not, I would like to recreate the `alert dialog` preventing the user to advance further.

**Is there a simple way of restarting the alert?**

### Alert Dialog

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
    LayoutInflater inflater = UserActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.no_location_alert_layout, null);
    alert.setView(layout);

    final EditText userCountryInput = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.alert_country_edit_text);
    final EditText userCityInput = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.alert_city_edit_text);

    alert.setTitle("Enter your details");
    alert.setMessage("Oops! Looks like you haven't added any current location details.");
    alert.setCancelable(false);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String userCountry = userCountryInput.getText().toString();
            String userCity = userCityInput.getText().toString();

            if (userCountry.isEmpty() && userCity.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter both your current city and country", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // HERE I NEED TO RESTART THE ALERT
            }
            else
            {
            // DO SOME STUFF
            }
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

Adding `alert.show()` results in this error:

```
 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4498)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4339)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4311)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:647)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:463)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:226)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:436)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:314)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:955)
    at com.example.android.booktrade_v10.ui.searchFeature.UserActivity$5.onClick(UserActivity.java:279)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Comment: Put the alert code on a function. If you need it, call that funct again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to restrict user access before pressing the `done` button by actually disabling the `button` according to one's needs( E.g. requesting user to type some info into `editText`) so therefore eliminating the need of restarting the dialog.

This is an example code below to disable a `positive` or `negative` button of an `alert dialog`

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
    LayoutInflater inflater = UserActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.no_location_alert_layout, null);
    alert.setView(layout);


    alert.setTitle("Enter your details");
    alert.setMessage("Oops! Looks like you haven't added any current location details.");
    alert.setCancelable(false);


    alert.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
             doSomething();
          }
    });
       // CREATE THE ACTUAL DIALOG
    final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.show();

  // MANIPULATE BUTTON

    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
            .setEnabled(false);

        if(constraint){
                        ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                        .setEnabled(true);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `alert.show();` to show the alert again.

Comment: I have tried this before posting. Please check my post edit.

Comment: @CatalinGhita Call `dialog.cancel();` before `alert.show();` I think that will fix the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error occurs even after adding that line.

Comment: You have `alert.setCancelable(false);` so `dialog.cancel();` won't do anything... it needs to be `dialog.dismiss();` instead. My bad. If that doesn't work, there is a more complex route of storing the AlertDialog that AlertDialog.Builder creates. You can then call dismiss() and show() directly on the AlertDialog itself rather than having to go through the DialogInterface.

Comment: `dialog.dismiss()` has no effect either. Still getting the error. Rather than storing AlertDialog's route, isn't there a work-around?